# Linking two classes with MVVM on different pages

Tags: c#, sqlite, class, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms problem with MVVM pattern. It is too large and too many pages to show all the code here, but it is very closely based on this project:
[Xamarin.Forms MVVM: How to Work with SQLite DB](https://medium.com/swlh/xamarin-forms-mvvm-how-to-work-with-sqlite-db-c-xaml-26fcae303edd)

The main difference is that I have two classes, school Terms and the Courses that belong with those terms, so almost everything else is doubled too. [Solution Explorer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOMhR.png) But SQLite doesn’t seem to allow foreign keys, and I can’t figure out how to automatically send the TermId to the CourseTermId field for the Course. (I am doing this for school, and we are not allowed to use a lot of plug-ins, so please don’t suggest those.)

You get to the Add Courses page from a button on the Term details page, so the correct Term is selected, and Add Courses is Modal, so the selected Term page is still available to it. Everything is bound through databindings, and everything else is working correctly, all my forms and pages. But I can’t connect that TermId to the Courses page.

It is possible I need a Global variable, since even though when running it should have Term.TermId available, it might not realize that while I am writing the program. If so, how do I do that and make sure it is updated each time I chose a different Term?

And once I have the TermId, how do I set the CourseTermId to match it? Everything else is set through databindings, I don’t know how to set something manually, or to equal something else.

```
//CourseViewModel.cs is where all of the Course variables are set, from the CourseDetails.Xaml page from bindings. 

public CourseViewModel(Course course)
{    
IDCourse = courseId;
courseId = course.CourseId;
courseName = course.CourseName;
courseTermId = course.CourseTermId;
….
}

private int _courseTermId;
public int courseTermId
{  get { return _courseTermId; }
set
{  SetValue(ref _courseTermId, value);
}}

    //Here is some of the CoursesDetailsPage.Xaml page. It isn’t pulling the Term.TermID this far, which is why I may need the Global Variable, 
//or a longer pathname? I wasn't trying to set it here, just show it to see if it was coming this far. It is set automatically as the Primary Key for Term.

<TableView Intent="Form" Margin="16,0">
<TableRoot>
<TableSection Title="Course">
<EntryCell Label="Course Name" Text="{Binding Path=Course.CourseName}" />
 <EntryCell Label="Course Term" Text="{Binding Path=Course.CourseTermId}" />
<EntryCell Label="Term ID" Text="{Binding Path=Term.TermId}" />
<EntryCell Label="Course ID" Text="{Binding Path=Course.CourseId}" />
….
</TableSection>


//Classes: There is more to the Course class, but that shouldn't matter.

    public class Term
    {
        
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int TermId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(255), Unique]
    public string TermName { get; set; }
        
    public string TermStart { get; set; }
    public string TermEnd { get; set; }
        
    public bool IsFinished { get; set; }
    }


    public class Course
    {
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int CourseId { get; set; }       
    public int CourseTermId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(250), Unique]
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public string CourseStatus { get; set; }
    ...
    }
```

Comment: you can get FK in Sqlite with https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/src/master/

Comment: but it sounds like you just need to pass the TermID as a parameter to your Courses page

Comment: As I said, it is for a school project and they don't let us use plugins, unfortunately. I haven’t had much luck trying to pass it as a parameter, since the Term isn’t chosen until the program is already running. I need to figure out how to pass the selected Term.
And once have it as a parameter, how/where do I set CoursesTermId = Term.TermId?

Comment: there is not enough code here for me to be able to give you a specific example.  But generally you would add a parameter to the page constructor, and pass that value when you create a new instance of the page before navigating to it

Comment: I am not supposed to use plugins, but I have tried that sqlite extentions, just to see if I could get it to work, and I wasn’t able to. I just tried again, and even downloading and using its own projects it doesn’t seem to recognize [ForeignKey] or [OneToMany]. I got: The type or namespace name 'IndexedAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: " almost everything else is doubled"? Post your two model classes please.

Comment: Once I get the parameter passed, how do I set it? Can I just say  courseTermId = Term.TermId; in the list,  or do I have to pass it into the regular setter in some way?

Comment: Please edit your post to include additional information.  Code crammed into a comment is not readable

Comment: I did post a picture of the Solution Explorer, showing all the pages. My classes are on different pages. There is a Term page, a Term Details page, then a Courses Page and a Courses Details page, etc. Once I can get the CourseTermId set, I get to figure out how to just list the courses for that term, but that will be a different question.

Comment: Option 1. Save TermID in course class. Option 2. Save a List<Course> with CourseID in term class. Then you can send either termID or courseID as a parameter when navigating to a course page. Then fetch the details from DB by ID.

Comment: HOW do I save TermID in the Course class. That is what I am trying to figure out. I am fairly new to programming, so sorry if I am being dense. If there is a way to upload my whole project somewhere so people can look at it I am willing to do so.

Comment: First, add "public int TermId" in course class. Then it depends on "How do you add a course". Do you add courses on mobile or import data into db. If you would like to add a course on mobile, you'll just need to select a termID on the page before saving the new course.

Comment: The user adds all of the Term and Course information in two different forms written in Xaml, except for TermId and CourseId, which are auto incremented, and that all works. I am trying to have the TermId passed automatically to Course and entered as CourseTermId, like a Foreign Key would be, rather than have the user have to do anything. That is the trouble I am having.

Comment: So how do you know the mappings with these two user forms? Sounds like you need one more table then.

Comment: I hadn't thought about it that way. I will work on that. Thank you.
But that brings me back to how to populate that class. Can you show me some code? Again, there are no foreign keys, so how to populate the class?

Comment: Also, you know which Term it should be because you originally add the course from the TermDetails page, which has the correct Term selected. Since it is a Modal page, that TermID should be accessible, and once the CourseTermId is set, it should be readonly from then on. That is the process I am trying to automate.

Comment: @TBaildon Could you provide the code with the screenshot of the results?

Comment: I ended up rewriting the whole thing without MVVM because I have a deadline and couldn't figure it out. But any way of passing something like a foreign key between two different classes in MVVM might be useful for others because I have not found anything online. I am still working on it in the new version, and hoping to use a global variable.